# Flink 1.9 with Steaming File Sink to S3 doesnt work

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am trying to use a Kafka consumer source with streaming file sink to S3

```
final StreamingFileSink<String> sink = StreamingFileSink
        .forRowFormat(new Path(“s3a://test/test”), new SimpleStringEncoder("UTF-8"))
        .withBucketAssigner(new DateTimeBucketAssigner(outputBucketFormat))
        .withRollingPolicy(rollingPolicy)
        .build();
```

I have `added s3a.access.key` and `s3a.secret.key` to `fink-conf.yaml` and copied `./opt/flink-s3-fs-hadoop-1.9.0.jar` to `./plugins/s3-fs-hadoop/` as mentioned in the documentation

But it doesn’t work , it doesn’t event throw any exception in the logs instead the processing is just stuck , If i use FileSystem sink it works fine.

Processing is stuck with the below logs:

```
2020-01-06 23:51:47,237 INFO  org.apache.flink.fs.shaded.hadoop3.org.apache.commons.beanutils.FluentPropertyBeanIntrospector - 
Error when creating PropertyDescriptor for public final void org.apache.flink.fs.shaded.hadoop3.org.apache.commons.configuration2.AbstractConfiguration.setProperty(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object)! Ignoring this property.

2020-01-06 23:51:47,249 WARN  org.apache.flink.fs.shaded.hadoop3.org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsConfig - 
Cannot locate configuration: tried hadoop-metrics2-s3a-file-system.properties,hadoop-metrics2.properties

2020-01-06 23:51:47,275 INFO  org.apache.flink.fs.shaded.hadoop3.org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl - 
Scheduled Metric snapshot period at 10 second(s).

2020-01-06 23:51:47,276 INFO  org.apache.flink.fs.shaded.hadoop3.org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl - 
s3a-file-system metrics system started
```

is any additonal config required for S3? Tested with both Flink versions: 1.9.0 and 1.9.1.

Found https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-14574 but even after putting the flink-s3-fs-hadoop jar under lib doesnt work. Please let me know if there is any working configuration with any of the flink images available on docker-hub

Comment: Do you have checkpointing enabled? Checkpointing is mandatory for using the streaming file sink.